# PHP string to json array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

So basically I'm making cURL request and getting response that looks like this(var_dump):

```
string(595) "{"user_id":1,"currency":"eur","purchase_packs":{"1":{"amount":500,"allowed_payment_methods":["ideal","paypal","visa","mc"]},"3":{"amount":1000,"allowed_payment_methods":["mc","ideal","paypal","visa"]},"6":{"amount":2500,"allowed_payment_methods":["mc","ideal","paypal"]},"8":{"amount":5000,"allowed_payment_methods":["ideal"]},"9":{"amount":10000,"allowed_payment_methods":["ideal"]}},"payment_methods":{"ideal":{"name":"ideal","allow_recurring":false},"paypal":{"name":"paypal","allow_recurring":false},"visa":{"name":"visa","allow_recurring":false},"mc":{"name":"mc","allow_recurring":false}}}"
```

What I want is to access it in the JS file like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    alert(data.user_id);
}
```

But I don't know how to convert(?) it properly.

And my next step(question) after that will be if I can do a for loop for every purchased pack, so I can create button for each one of them

Probably something like this:

```
var pack;
var packs = data.purchase_packs;
for (pack= 0; pack < packs.length; pack++) {
    console.log(packs[pack]);
}
```

Comment: your js ajax call if using jquery can have the response type specified so it'll take the json returned from your php and store it as a local object you can then access.

Comment: don't need to convert it in php to anything...it's already a JSON string. Just echo string for ajax to consume

Comment: Well, I've tried without converting it, just echo the string and when I do this: data.user_id it says it's undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm tried to understand your "question"....

In js:

```
$.post('/some/url',{query: 'somequery'},
function (data) {
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    console.log(data);
});
```

In PHP:

```
data = json_decode(rtrim($myJSONEncodedString, "\0"));
if (!empty($data->purchase_packs)
    foreach ($data->purchase_packs as $key => $value)
        var_dump($value);
```

Comment: JSON parse did the job for proper access to the elements. But the for loop needs to be in the javascript part of the code, not PHP.
Rajiv Ranjan's answer works. So both of you helped me. How to pick the best answer in this case?

Comment: Click on "Accept this answer" that is under answer votes counter

Comment: I know how to accept an answer. I just don't know which one to choose. But I'll go with yours since you was faster and this was first part of my question.

Answer (score 2):

After receiving response using cURL, just echo that json string between `<script></script>` tag.

Then json string will look like:

```
<script>
var jsondata = {"user_id":1,"currency":"eur","purchase_packs":{"1":{"amount":500,"allowed_payment_methods":["ideal","paypal","visa","mc"]},"3":{"amount":1000,"allowed_payment_methods":["mc","ideal","paypal","visa"]},"6":{"amount":2500,"allowed_payment_methods":["mc","ideal","paypal"]},"8":{"amount":5000,"allowed_payment_methods":["ideal"]},"9":{"amount":10000,"allowed_payment_methods":["ideal"]}},"payment_methods":{"ideal":{"name":"ideal","allow_recurring":false},"paypal":{"name":"paypal","allow_recurring":false},"visa":{"name":"visa","allow_recurring":false},"mc":{"name":"mc","allow_recurring":false}}};
</script>
```

Then, your javascript code between `<script></script>`. Like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    alert(jsondata.user_id); // return user_id value

    jQuery.each(jsondata.purchase_packs, function(i, val) {   
      alert(val.amount); // return amount
      var paymentMethod = val.allowed_payment_methods;
      jQuery.each(paymentMethod, function() {
          alert(this); // will return all payment gateway method
        });     
    });
</script>
```

Hope will help!